# Conditionally modify text in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to modify some multiline string data in text file. I'm able to read the whole file content to a variable and catch the part of the data which I'm interested in. Then in a separate variable I modify its content. I want to save the data back to the file. Here is an example of what I have:

```
Value1: something 
        something else
Value2: something else 1
        something else 2
Value3: something else 4
        something else 5
```

and here is what I want to achieve:

```
Value1: something 
        something else
Value2: MODIFIED DATA 1
        MODIFIED DATA 2
Value3: something else 4
        something else 5
```

It's not a simple regex replace, because I need to verify content of the searched text and conditionally modify it.

Comment: What do you want to modify it from/to?

Comment: Content of `Value2` needs to be modified.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. What is the current content of `Value2`, and what do you want to modify it to?

Comment: Ok lemme explain more specific. I have `list of strings` which needs to be first cleaned from commentary which starts with `#` sign then I need to check if this string is contained in other array and if it is not I have to remove it from text.

Comment: @J33nn clarify with edit to the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a multiline regex replacement. It's a replacement repeated in multiple lines and can be solved in a one-liner with a flip-flop, like:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '
  if ( $ff = (m/^Value2:/ ... /^\S/) ) { 
    unless ( $ff =~ m/E0$/ ) { 
      s/something else/MODIFIED DATA/ 
    } 
  }
' infile
```

It applies the substitution command for all lines between one that begins with `Value2:` and another that begins with a non-blank character.

The previous command yields:

```
Value1: something
        something else
Value2: MODIFIED DATA 1
        MODIFIED DATA 2
Value3: something else 4
        something else 5
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to go from

```
Value2: something else 1
        something else 2
```

to

```
Value2: MODIFIED DATA 1
        MODIFIED DATA 2
```

The regexp for this would be `/Value2:\s*(.*?)\s*\n\s*(.*?)\s*\n/m`, assuming you know `Value2` to put it in the regex and your "something else" does not contain `\n`. It's hard to provide more help without more details about your data.

Comment: It can't be done with simple regex because there is more conditions to be met for every single line in `Value2` field.

Answer (score 0):

Using In-place editor in a script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $filename = 'some_file.txt';

# For Testing - Initialize file with fake data.
open my $fh, '>', $filename;
$fh->print(<DATA>);
close $fh;

# Use In-place editor
my $section = 'Value2';
my $newtext = "Value2: MODIFIED DATA 1\n        MODIFIED DATA 2\n";
{
    local @ARGV = ($filename);
    local $^I = '.bac';

    while (<>) {
        if ( my $linenum = /^$section:/ ... /^\S/) {
            unless ($linenum =~ /E0/) { # Skip next section
                # Replace first line with entire new text, gobble other lines
                $_ = $linenum == 1 ? $newtext : '';
            }
        }
        print;
    }

    unlink "$filename$^I";
}

# For Testing - Print results of file.
print "Results:\n";
open $fh, '<', $filename;
print(<$fh>);
close $fh;

1;

__DATA__
Value1: something 
        something else
Value2: something else 1
        something else 2
        something else 3
Value3: something else 4
        something else 5
```